# Не отрабатывает ожидание в Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

Я собираю в List ссылки со страницы, после хочу в цикле перейти по всем ссылкам, но с задержкой. Ссылки открываются одна за одной без тайм аута. Я много гуглил, но к сожалению не нашел почему так. Я создаю новый драйвер и только на него вешаю тайм аут. Прибегнул к созданию явного ожидания, с использованием собственного класса реализующего ExpectedCondition, который содержит в себе Thread.sleap(), чисто под стайл Selenium сделал, но не могу поверить , что нет Selenium ожидания нет обыкновенного явного ожидание на поток.

Есть мысль:

1. Ожидание вешается на страницу а не образуется в потоке.
2. Проблема с версией браузера и т.п.

Если я что-то не так понимаю, дайте знать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не вставляйте код картинкой - скопировать для ответа чтобы подправить невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в цикле идет открытие ссылок одна за другой. Если нужна задержка между открытиями, делайте ее явно:

```
listPost.forEach(e -> {
    dTest.get(e.getLink());
    Thread.sleep(5000);
});
```

Тут после открытия каждой ссылки будет пауза 5 секунд.